# Having trouble referencing ClassLibrary package project from console app webjob project

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, class-library, azure-webjobs

I created a new console app webjob project in visual by selecting New Project -> Cloud -> Azure WebJob.

I then added a "Class Library (Package)" project to my solution but having trouble referencing the class library project from the WebJob project.

If I use an old-fashioned Class Library project, it works without a problem. Any idea why I can't reference a class library package project from an Azure WebJob project?

Comment: I am facing the similar issue. What do you mean by "old-fashioned" class library referencing way?

Answer (score 0):

Class Library (Package) is specifically designed for creating NuGet packages. You should use the "old-fashioned" class library.